# update a text file in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, text-files

I have a text file. I need to find some data and update some data. Let me explain it with an example.
This is my text file:

```
NAME:Date
VALUE:02/03/2011
NAME:NoOfPages
VALUE:250
…
…
…
…
Total_Size:45725
```

I need to update 250 and 45725 values. So Im looking to do it using Regular Expression. Is it the best way to do that or is there any better method to do this.
Can anyone can help to do it.

Im using C# and VS 2008. My application is windows based application.

Comment: Do you have the file in memory, i.e. you want to find and replace in a string, or do you have in on disk, i.e. you can stream through a line at a time? Do you want to update the file in place, or write a temporary copy and rename over or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex in your case. 
It seems to be a short `name:value` list.

I would suggest using a `state` variable.

1. Read line by line.
2. `Split` using `:` character.
3. Make a `switch` statement on the first part of the split.

   - if it is `NAME` then store the second part in the state value. ***Write*** the line.
   - if it is `VALUE` then

     - if the `state` value correspond to a field you must update: ***write*** the line with the **new** value.
     - else ***write*** the line as is.
4. Loop to 1 until `EOF`

Would it be possible in your case?